# Spring REST with both JSON and XML

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I want to provide **one** comprehensive REST API with support for both `JSON` and `XML`.

The domain model is of complex type and we note that to produce friendly `JSON` and `XML` on the same model using `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` and `JaxbMarshaller` respectively tends to give *either* readable XML or readable JSON <sup>1)</sup>.

What's the best way to proceed?

<sup>1) Due to how objects such as maps, root tags and relations are modelled differently in `json` than in `xml`, the objects to serialize needs to be designed differently to get both tidy `json` and tidy `xml`. Utilities such as jaxb annotations only goes that far.</sup>

---

I can think of a few candidates

### 1) Create both a json and xml controller/model

```
public class Controller { 
   public Foo foo() { 
       return new Foo(); 
   } 
}

public class XmlController extends Controller {
   @Override
   public XmlFoo foo() { 
       return new new XmlFoo(super.foo()); 
   } 
}

public class JsonController extends Controller {
   @Override
   public JsonFoo foo() { 
       return new JsonFoo(super.foo()); 
   } 
}
```

Given a model object `Foo` create a `JsonFoo` and `XmlFoo`

### 2) Write a custom message converter

I tried this and it turned out to be a bit complicated since the view must know how to resolve e.g., a `Foo` to a `JsonFoo` to be able to serialize it into a readable format.

### 3) Let each model object serialize itself, e.g.,

```
public class Foo {
    public String serialize(Serializer s) {
       return s.serialize(this);
    }
}
```

Based on some arbitration parameter let the controller inject the correct serializer

```
new Foo(new FooJsonSerializer());
new Foo(new FooXmlSerializer());
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by needing different designs?

Comment: JAXB for example can be used to map from/to both XML and JSON with the same annotated class. No need for different design.

Comment: @chrylis, it's far from trivial to constuct an elaborate java structure which can serialize to both pretty json and pretty xml.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg Ah, I didn't get from your question that you were asking about nested/hierarchical data structures. It seems to me that when you hit the point where you're needing to coordinate the design of the serialization and the POJO, you've hit the point where a custom serializer for the object makes sense.

Comment: Why is everyone using view resolvers? They are intended for humans. Message converters are made exactly for M2M communication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm doing this in a current project without using a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`. For *one* method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<BasicResponse> getBasicResponse() {
    return new HttpEntity<BasicResponse>(new BasicResponse());
}
```

I can receive the following output based on the `Accept` request header.

**Accept: application/xml** (requires JAXB2 on the classpath)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<basicResponse>
    <errors>
        <message>test1</message>
        <message>test2</message>
    </errors>
</basicResponse>
```

**Accept: application/json** (requires Jackson on the classpath)

```
{
    "errors" : ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

My response object is simple and uses normal annotations:

```
package org.mypackage.response;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BasicResponse {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "errors")
    @XmlElement(name = "message")
    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    public BasicResponse() {
        this.errors.add("test1");
        this.errors.add("test2");
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

}
```

The [SpringSource spring-mvc-showcase project](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase) is also a helpful resource. I think they separate the conversions for different methods, but I am definitely doing this for one method.

I can't quite tell by your question...but if you're looking to serialize the output more than that, @chrylis is correct in that a custom serializer would be your next move. But everything I've ran into (which can get pretty complex, with nested objects in my response) converts perfectly to valid XML or JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wasn't clear enough in my question. I too get valid xml & json, but a pretty xml api becomes an ugly json api and the other way around. I think @chrylis was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html).

There is an issue in that a collection of POJOs are not mapped correctly with some XML marshallers. XStream has solutions for this (Moxy too?).

Here's a place to start:

http://blog.springsource.org/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views/

Basically, you use a MappingJacksonView and a similar one for XML, which is a "fake" view that uses Jackson (or an XML marshaller) to marshall your POJO(s) to the correct format.

The server will send back the correct type based on one of:

- the HTTP Accept header
- a "filetype extension", such as ".json"
- a querystring parameter, such as "format=json"

Answer (score 0):

As far as omitting fields, you cans use annotations @JsonIgnore(for Jackson) and/or @XStreamOmitField(for XStream).

Did you try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", 
method = RequestMethod.GET,
headers ={"Accept=application/json,application/xml"},
produces={"application/json", "application/xml"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, You could configure in Spring

```
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer
        .favorParameter(true)
        .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
        .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
}

@GetMapping(value = "/health")
public Health health() {
    return Health.builder().name("Application").status("UP").build();
}
```

http://localhost:18050/api/ping/health?format=xml

http://localhost:18050/api/ping/health?format=json